# Severity: Notice Message: Undefined variable: data Filename: frontend/v_grafik.php Line Number: 17

Tags: codeigniter-3

> CodeIgniter, Message: Undefined variable, Passing data
>
> Controller

```
function v_grafik() {

        // error_reporting(0);
        $iklan     = $this->Tb_iklan_model->get_all();
        $berita    = $this->Tb_berita_model->get_all();   
        $x['data'] = $this->M_grafik->get_data_stok();
        
        if ($x) {
         $data   = array(
            'x'       => $x,         
            'berita'  => $berita,         
            'iklan'   => $iklan,
            'content' => "frontend/v_grafik",
        );  
            // $content = $this->load->view('frontend/v_grafik',$x);
            $this->load->view('layout/frontend', $data);
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Record Not Found');
            redirect(site_url('frontend'));
        }
    }
```

> View

```
<?php
        foreach($data as $data){
            $merk[] = $data->merk;
            $stok[] = (float) $data->stok;
        }
    ?>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="280"></canvas>
  <!--Load chart js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/vendor/chartjs/Chart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/vendor/chartjs/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script>
            var lineChartData = {
                labels : <?php echo json_encode($merk);?>,
                datasets : [
                    {
                        fillColor: "rgba(60,141,188,0.9)",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(60,141,188,0.8)",
                        pointColor: "#3b8bba",
                        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(152,235,239,1)",
                        data : <?php echo json_encode($stok);?>
                    }
                ]
            }
    var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData);
</script>
```

> This eror : A PHP Error was encountered
> Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: frontend/v_grafik.php

Line Number: 17

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\application\views\frontend\v_grafik.php
Line: 17

> This Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: frontend/v_grafik.php

Line Number: 17

- Can help me?

Comment: So could you please enlighten us as to the code that is on Line 17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you do... In your view

```
foreach($data as $data)
```

You are changing what $data is and bad things will happen. So you need to change one of them. In this "example" I have changed the 2nd occurrence of $data to $info.

```
foreach($data as $info){
  $merk[] = $info->merk;
  $stok[] = (float) $info->stok;
}
```